I want to use the SQLQueryChain method, but I am not being able to find it's import is deprecated
I am building a Chatbot in which I have to use Langchain's SQLQueryChain for which I am using
from langchain.chains.sql_database import SQLQueryChain. But this is not recognised, so I don't have any idea. How can I fulfill my requirement?
Below is my code:
# Importing necessary libraries and modules

from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase
from langchain.chains.sql_database import SQLQueryChain
from langchain.llms.openai import OpenAI
import sqlalchemy  # For interacting with SQL databases

# Configuration for OpenAI and SQLDatabase
api_key = "your_openai_api_key" 
db_uri = "your_database_uri"  

# Creating instances of SQLDatabase and SQLQueryChain
sql_database = SQLDatabase.from_uri(db_uri)
sql_chain = SQLQueryChain(
    llm=OpenAI(api_key=api_key),
    database=sql_database,
)

# Function to execute SQL queries and return results
def execute_sql_query(sql_query):
    # Connect to the database
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db_uri)
    with engine.connect() as connection:
        # Execute the SQL query and fetch the results
        result = connection.execute(sql_query).fetchall()
    return result

I tried searching all the latest import statements to find the SQLQueryChain import but i couldn't find it.

if you get error then show it in question (not in comments)

did you search in documentation? Maybe they moved it into different module. OR maybe it needs to install extra module.

where did you find information about SQLQueryChain? Add link in question (not in comment). I checked source code and there is only function langchain.chains.sql_database.query.create_sql_query_chain(). You can use import langchain.chains.sql_database and later print( import langchain.chains.sql_database.__file__ ) to get /full/path/to/sql_database/__init__.py on your computer and you can see what is in source code in all files in folder sql_database.

I can't find SQLQueryChain with Google (except example in js) so I checked source code.
I found
langchain.chains.sql_database.query.create_sql_query_chain()

which seems similar to example in js
Later I found it in documentation for Python: create_sql_query_chain

BTW:
You can find source code on local computer using __file__
import langchain.chains.sql_database

print( langchain.chains.sql_database.__file__ )

It gives /full/path/to/sql_database/__init__.py and you can use its part (in system shell) to see all files in folder sql_database
cd /full/path/to/sql_database/
ls   # or `dir` on Windows

And here source code for query.py on GitHub

EDIT:
Example from docstring in query.py
It seems you can use shorter langchain.chains.create_sql_query_chain
# pip install -U langchain langchain-community langchain-openai

from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import create_sql_query_chain
from langchain_community.utilities import SQLDatabase

db = SQLDatabase.from_uri("sqlite:///Chinook.db")
llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0)
chain = create_sql_query_chain(llm, db)
response = chain.invoke({"question": "How many employees are there"})

